# How can 1 button change text in multiple text boxes at the same time or in sequence?

Tags: android

Okay so just to give a little more info, im very new to coding and there is obviosly alot that I dont know.

I have a button and then I have 7 textview boxes

At this moment if I press the button it will choose a random number and change the textview box 1, how can I make it so that when I press the button it actions this method on all 7 textview boxes, it can not have the same output thought.

I am choosing a random number between 1 and 49 , so each text box should do that but show different answers.

```
package za.co.gypsyhost.test;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.Random;



public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

public void generate(View view) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int number = rand.nextInt(49) + 1;
    TextView myText;
    myText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum1);
    String myString = String.valueOf(number);
    myText.setText(myString);
}

}
```

Here is the rest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="generate"
        android:text="Button"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="36dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="381dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Number" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum4"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum5"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum6"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lottoNum7"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="TextView" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: its simple store textView in ArrayList<TextView> and OnClick chage as u want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

     ArrayList<TextView> textViews=new ArrayList<>();
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum1));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum2));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum3));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum4));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum5));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum6));
        textViews.add((TextView) findViewById(R.id.lottoNum7));

}

public void generate(View view) {

        for(int i=0;i<textViews.size();i++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int number = rand.nextInt(49) + 1;
            String myString = String.valueOf(number);
            textViews.get(i).setText(myString);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Ashvin, this works perfectly! Now I just need to understand how it works, I want to learn and not just copy and paste but thanks you sir

Comment: @QuentinO anytime sir